# PiCamera out of resources no matter what

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, camera

I started trying the official test code;

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
sleep(5)
camera.stop_preview()
```

And I got this error;

```
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources
```

This is immediately after a reboot, no running scripts or processes, camera verified enabled in raspi-config via terminal and the Raspberry Pi Configuration app, and GPU memory increased to 256. I know the camera works because I can use the RPi Cam Web Interface and see the camera feed just fine (I uninstalled it afterwards to see if it was conflicting, which it apparently wasn't.) I've already updated and upgraded, and I can't run rpi_update even if I wanted to because it says "Invalid git hash specified" when I type "y" to proceed. I've reached the limit of troubleshooting, and reddit deletes my post instantly because the bot says I didn't research.

From the command prompt, I did some basic troubleshooting at the basic level. Copied directly from the console:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=1
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -o image.jpg
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: From the command prompt, I did some basic troubleshooting at the basic level. Copied directly from the console: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=1
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -o image.jpg
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates

pi@raspberrypi:~ $

Comment: What model pi are you using and how much memory does it have.

Comment: I'm using the model 4B with 4GB ram

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same thing, I've exhausted troubleshooting for picamera 1 (w/ legacy support enabled). However picamera2 (w/ legacy mode disabled) works great.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain.

MMAL stuff often means something else is using the camera, OR the camera thinks that.

You're lucky you aren't getting the timed out error. Nobody at Raspberry Pi cares about that one at all.